# Determine if /dev/random slows down processes

Tags: linux, performance, security, random

Does linux provide a way for (or some statistics about) `/dev/random` in order to answer the question:

Is there enough entropy in a system to feed the secure random number generators -  or if `/dev/random` potentially **slows down processes**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the [random(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/random.4.html) man page. It mentions reading sequentially 
`/proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail` (a read-only textual pseudo file); see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) for details about `/proc/` pseudo-file-system.

You could just read `/dev/urandom` BTW which won't block (but might be "less" random).

BTW, you might perhaps [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) the fd for `/dev/random` before reading it (if you want to avoid being blocked, or use [fcntl(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) for non blocking mode with `O_NONBLOCK` etc...).

See also kernel's [hw_random.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/hw_random.txt)

NB: notice that some other process might read `/dev/random` too...